# Getting started with Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm an Ext veteran but have a few rather simple mobile apps i need to create and naturally i'm looking at sencha touch. Ting is - most of the examples don't run up in Firefox/Opera.

I'm happily using Monodevelop as my IDE - this will have an Asp.NET backend - but can't even get the most basic setup working with ST....

What does everyone use for their development setups? How do you debug your apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working in a vaguely similar scenario, and I mostly go for Google Chrome's Developer Tools or sometimes Safari developer tools, that's far from perfect but at least something.

However, I often try to isolate out problems not directly tied to the interface and then go back and solve them with Firefox/Firebug, which I find the absolutely superior development environment. It's often more than you think, especially if you're experienced with TDD. Try QUnit, for example ( http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit ).

It's probably possible to use Apple's developer tools (XCode/Dashcode or whatever..) for a more ergonomic experience, but I still can't be bothered.

(Here's to hoping for more compatible mobile web frameworks! I want my Firebug!)

Answer (score 1):

They have explicitly stated that Sencha Touch only works on Web-kit browsers, namely Chrome and Safari

Comment: This is correct, at the moment we only support Webkit browsers because they have the overwhelming share of quality shipped implementations on actual devices. Support for more platforms is on the way however.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS 2008 SP1 with a large solution in TFS with a web application that hosts the JSON WCF services and Sencha Touch clients for iPad, iPhone and more. I have it working with WCF and am still learning myself. I admit it was quite a bear to learn, but things are starting to work. I have lists sizing to the client as expected too. The hardest part was the fact that Casini only hosts locally so we need to publish the web application to test with real iPads and iPhones. I also use Safari in OSX to help debug.

Answer (score 0):

I sat around with Chrome, an iPhone and the Android emulator when I did my first one. I thought multi browser testing was bad normally but it's nothing compared to all the different Android versions, densities etc.

Chrome developer tools was the best I could manage on the PC though.

Answer (score 0):

The best IDE I've come accross is Netbeans. Here's a guide to start you off : 
http://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/using-netbeans-ide-with-sencha-touch/

The browsers you can test it on are : Safari, Chrome

The OS's on which it works : Android, iOS, BB6+

Hope this helps 
Cheers :)